# How to mock Solrclient request for java?

Tags: java, mockito, solrj, powermockito, solrclient

I have a java code to establish a connection to the Solr server. I am not sure how I can mock it. Please check my code below.

```
SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(url).build();
QueryResponse res = solrClient.query(solrQuery);
SolrDocumentList results = res.getResults();
```

Can someone please tell me how I can mock the above logic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you are actually trying to test. You could do something like:

```
QueryResponse emptyResponse = new QueryResponse();
emptyResponse.setResponse(new NamedList<>(Map.of("response", new SolrDocumentList())));
when(solrClientMock.query(any())).thenReturn(emptyResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you, Ahmad.